# C# Entity Framework using only one ObjectContext per HttpContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, objectcontext

In ASP.NET MVC 2, using Entity Framework 4,  I'm getting this error "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker".

A search of SO shows that it is probably because I have different instances of the Entity Framework ObjectContext, when it should be only one ObjectContext instance for each HttpContext.

I have this code (written long before I joined) that appears to do just that - have one ObjectContext for every HttpContext.  But I am getting the "IEntityChangeTracker" exception frequently so it is probably not working as intended:

```
// in ObjectContextManager.cs
public const string ConnectionString = "name=MyAppEntities";
public const string ContainerName = "MyAppEntities";

public static ObjectContext GetObjectContext()
{
    ObjectContext objectContext = GetCurrentObjectContext();
    if (objectContext == null) // create and store the object context
    {   
        objectContext = new ObjectContext(ConnectionString, ContainerName);     
        objectContext.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;    
        StoreCurrentObjectContext(objectContext);
    }
    return objectContext;
}

private static void StoreCurrentObjectContext(ObjectContext objectContext)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains("EF.ObjectContext"))
        HttpContext.Current.Items["EF.ObjectContext"] = objectContext;
    else
        HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("EF.ObjectContext", objectContext);
}

private static ObjectContext GetCurrentObjectContext()
{
    ObjectContext objectContext = null;
    if (HttpContext.Current.Items.Contains("EF.ObjectContext")
        objectContext = (ObjectContext)HttpContext.Current.Items["EF.ObjectContext"];
    return objectContext;
}
```

I've examined this code and it looks correct.  It does as far as I can tell return one ObjectContext instance for each HttpContext.  Is the code wrong?

If the code is not wrong, why else would I get the "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker" exception?

EDIT: To show how the ObjectContext is disposed:

```
// in HttpRequestModule.cs
private void Application_EndRequest(object source, EventArgs e)
{
    ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IRepositoryContext>().Terminate();
}

// in RepositoryContext.cs
public void Terminate() 
{
    ObjectContextManager.RemoveCurrentObjectContext();
}

// in ObjectContextManager.cs
public static void RemoveCurrentObjectContext()
{
    ObjectContext objectContext = GetCurrentObjectContext();
    if (objectContext != null)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Items.Remove("EF.ObjectContext");
        objectContext.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: are you disposing the context in the EndRequest method?

Comment: Updated to show disposal method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My guess is that you've stored an object somewhere in memory (most likely the http cache using in-process mode, but could also be any manual cache such as a shared dictionary), and now you've somehow associated that object with something else, for example:

```
newOrder.OwnerUser = currentUser; // <== let's say currentUser came from cache
                                  // and newOrder was on your new entity context
```

Hence, a problem if the cached object still thinks it is attached to a context; not least, you are probably keeping an entire graph alive accidentally.

---

The code looks OK (as long as you are disposing it at the end of the request), but this would be a good time to add:

```
private const string EFContextKey = "EF.ObjectContext";
```

and use that in place of the 5 literals. Avoids a few risks ;p

Comment: Actually I have stored an object in cache (Currency DefaultCurrency) and then attached it to the order object (order.Currency = DefaultCurrency) - and that is exactly where the exception is thrown .. That is a very promising lead.  When I saved DefaultCurrency to cache it is of type `System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Currency_F4008E27DE_etc` instead of the POCO class `Entities.Currency`.  What do I need to do with this object to be able to safely store it in the cache and then add it to another object later, detach it?

Comment: @JK - tricky; since there may be multiple threads trying to use it at once, the best thing I can suggest is to write some code that clones it (creating a vanilla POCO that isn't attached to the context), and *store* a clone (avoids the risk of keeping a graph alive), and clone it *again* every time you fetch it out. I don't know if it is possible in EF, but if this was L2S I'd be setting the  `DefaultCurrencyId` rather than `DefaultCurrency` - avoids a few problem cases.

Comment: Thanks I will see what I can do there